# When did UITableViewCell done layout subview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uistackview

As shown in the following image, I want to add a tip(subview of the biggest UIView) that left align with the UIStackView in UITableViewCell. The width of UIStackView in UITableViewCell is dynamic, so I need to place the tip view after the UITableViewCell layout its subviews.

I've tried to add the tip view in willDisplayCell function, but the position I get there is not the final position.

Also, I tried to set the tip view's position in the UITableViewCell's layoutSubviews function. Since this function is called multiple times, the tip will go to the expected place eventually, but it will flicker at the beginning.

So in which function should I add the tip view?

--------Edited--------

Add a code snippet to make it clearer. I just want to know where should I put the following code, so that rect.origin.x is the final position of the stackview.

```
UIView *view = self.view;
CGRect rect = [cell.stackView convertRect:cell.stackView.bounds toView:view];
[self.tipView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:view.leadingAnchor constant:rect.origin.x].active = YES;
[self.tipView.trailingAnchor constraintLessThanOrEqualToAnchor:view.trailingAnchor constant:-marginConstant].active = YES;
[self.tipView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.tableView.bottomAnchor constant:-TSkBubbleClickAreaHeight-marginConstant].active = YES;
[view layoutIfNeeded];
```

[image]

Comment: Are you adding your `tipView` as a subview of the cell, but positioned outside the bounds of the cell? Or is it a subview of the table view, positioned relative to the content of a specific cell? It will help if you show the code you are currently working on - see: [mre].

Comment: @DonMag As mentioned above, the tipView is added as a subview of the outside biggest UIView.

Comment: OK - still a bit unclear though... are you showing a "tip view" for every row? Only one row? Supposed to scroll with the cells?

Comment: @DonMag I'm showing tipView for only one row and there's only one tipView in the biggest UIView. The tipView will be dismissed when cells scroll. I added some code above, hope this can make my question clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

To try and directly answer your question, you know when the layout of the content of the cell is completely finished when whatever you're doing to the cell is done. So, to know exactly when your cell's Stack View has been laid-out, you could subclass the stack view and implement `layoutSubviews` in that subclass.

---

Since it's still not clear *exactly* what you're doing, I'll offer a couple approaches...

If you are calling `reloadData` on the table view, you could try this:

```
[tableView reloadData];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self showTipView:pth];
});
```

If you are calling `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`, you could try this:

```
[CATransaction begin];

[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    [self showTipView:pth];
}];

[self->tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[pth] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

[CATransaction commit];
```

Here's an example (I've tried to keep it simple, and provide clear comments):

**ExampleTableViewCell.h**

```
//
//  ExampleTableViewCell.h
//  Created by Don Mag on 9/15/20.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
@interface ExampleTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
- (void) configureCell:(NSString *)s;
- (UIStackView *)getStackRef;
@end
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

---

**ExampleTableViewCell.m**

```
//
//  ExampleTableViewCell.m
//  Created by Don Mag on 9/15/20.
//

#import "ExampleTableViewCell.h"

@interface ExampleTableViewCell ()
{
    UIStackView *stackView;
    UILabel *label;
}
@end

@implementation ExampleTableViewCell

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) commonInit {
    label = [UILabel new];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    stackView = [UIStackView new];
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    
    [stackView addArrangedSubview:label];
    
    [self.contentView addSubview:stackView];
    
    UILayoutGuide *g = self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide;
    
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        
        // constrain stack view Top: 0 / Trailing: 0 / Bottom: 0
        [stackView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor constant:0.0],
        [stackView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.trailingAnchor constant:0.0],
        [stackView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.bottomAnchor constant:0.0],

    ]];

}
- (void) configureCell:(NSString *)s {
    label.text = s;
}

- (UIStackView *)getStackRef {
    return stackView;
}

@end
```

---

**ExampleViewController.h**

```
//
//  ExampleViewController.h
//  Created by Don Mag on 9/15/20.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
@interface ExampleViewController : UIViewController
@end
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

---

**ExampleViewController.m**

```
//
//  ExampleViewController.m
//  Created by Don Mag on 9/15/20.
//

#import "ExampleViewController.h"
#import "ExampleTableViewCell.h"

@interface ExampleViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray *myData;
    NSMutableArray *sampleStrings;
    
    UIView *tipView;
    
    UIButton *reloadButton;
    UIButton *insertButton;
    UITableView *tableView;
    
    NSInteger idx;
    NSInteger insertRow;
}
@end

@implementation ExampleViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // row number to insert and show the tipView
    insertRow = 7;
    
    // init some sample data
    myData = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %i", i];
        [myData addObject:s];
    }
    
    // a few example strings
    sampleStrings = [NSMutableArray new];
    [sampleStrings addObject:@"Short text example."];
    [sampleStrings addObject:@"A little more text example."];
    [sampleStrings addObject:@"Considerably longer text for this example."];
    
    // index for sampleStrings array
    idx = -1;

    // create a "tip view"
    //  red background view with
    //  green background label
    //  label is inset 4-pts on each side
    tipView = [UIView new];
    tipView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    UILabel *tipLabel = [UILabel new];
    tipLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    tipLabel.text = @"This is the tip!";
    
    tipView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    tipLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    
    [tipView addSubview:tipLabel];
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        [tipLabel.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:tipView.topAnchor constant:4.0],
        [tipLabel.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:tipView.leadingAnchor constant:4.0],
        [tipLabel.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:tipView.bottomAnchor constant:-4.0],
        [tipLabel.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:tipView.trailingAnchor constant:-4.0],
    ]];
    
    // init buttons
    reloadButton = [UIButton new];
    [reloadButton setTitle:@"Reload" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [reloadButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [reloadButton setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [reloadButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    insertButton = [UIButton new];
    [insertButton setTitle:@"Insert" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [insertButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [insertButton setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [insertButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    
    // init table view
    tableView = [UITableView new];
    
    for (UIView *v in @[reloadButton, insertButton, tableView]) {
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:v];
    }
    
    UILayoutGuide *g = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide;
    
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        
        // buttons at top
        [reloadButton.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor constant:20.0],
        [reloadButton.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.leadingAnchor constant:24.0],
        
        [insertButton.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor constant:20.0],
        [insertButton.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.trailingAnchor constant:-24.0],
        
        [insertButton.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:reloadButton.trailingAnchor constant:20.0],
        [insertButton.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:reloadButton.widthAnchor],
        
        // constrain tableView Top: 20-pts from buttons / Leading: 0 / Trailing: 0 / Bottom: 0
        [tableView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:reloadButton.bottomAnchor constant:20.0],
        [tableView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.leadingAnchor constant:0.0],
        [tableView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.trailingAnchor constant:0.0],
        [tableView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.bottomAnchor constant:0.0],
        
    ]];
    
    [tableView registerClass:[ExampleTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"exCell"];

    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    
    [reloadButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [insertButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [tipView removeFromSuperview];
}
- (void)btnTap:(UIButton *)btn {
    
    // remove tipView if it's showing
    [tipView removeFromSuperview];

    NSString *s = sampleStrings[++idx % 3];

    if (btn == reloadButton) {
        [self reloadMethod:s];
    } else {
        [self insertMethod:s];
    }
}
- (void)insertMethod:(NSString *)s {
    
    // IndexPath for cell you want
    __block NSIndexPath *pth = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:insertRow inSection:0];
    
    [myData insertObject:s atIndex:pth.row];
    
    [CATransaction begin];
    
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        [self showTipView:pth];
    }];

    [self->tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[pth] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    
    [CATransaction commit];
}
- (void)reloadMethod:(NSString *)s {

    // IndexPath for cell you want
    __block NSIndexPath *pth = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:insertRow inSection:0];

    [myData insertObject:s atIndex:pth.row];

    [tableView reloadData];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self showTipView:pth];
    });
    
}
- (void)showTipView:(NSIndexPath *)pth {
    
    // get a reference to the cell
    ExampleTableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:pth];
    
    // if row is not visible
    if (!cell) {
        return;
    }
    
    // get a reference to the cell's stack view
    UIStackView *stack = [cell getStackRef];
    
    // add tipView to self.view
    [self.view addSubview:tipView];
    
    // constrain tipView
    //  Leading to stack view's Leading
    //  Bottom to cell's Top - 4
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        [tipView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:stack.leadingAnchor constant:0.0],
        [tipView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:cell.topAnchor constant:-4.0],
    ]];
    
    // if we want to "fade-in" the tipView
    [tipView setAlpha:0.0];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{
        [self->tipView setAlpha:1.0];
    }];
    
}

- (nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ExampleTableViewCell *c = (ExampleTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"exCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [c configureCell:myData[indexPath.row]];
    return c;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [myData count];
}

@end
```

Comment: No, the table view is not static, the cell is inserted after viewDidAppear, so we cannot put it there.

Comment: @ArgenBarbie - ok... if you edit your question with a clear explanation of what you're trying to do - best, if you can include example code to reproduce the issue - I'll try and help (otherwise, as we see here, I'm trying to answer a different question).

Comment: I said at the beginning that the stack view in cell is dynamic, what I'm looking for is a place where the UITableViewCell did layout its subviews.

Comment: @ArgenBarbie - ok, in general, when someone says "dynamic" they mean it will be a variable size (based on text in a label, for example) when it is displayed ... which is what I did in my example code. Are you saying that, based on maybe user interaction, you are changing the content of the red stack view, while it is *already* displayed? Or are you inserting the row and reloading the table? Or inserting the row in a `performBatchUpdates` block?

Comment: Yes, you can think that I'm inserting the row and reloading the table.

Comment: Thanks @DonMag, I thought too complicated... Just call showTipView after reloadTable works well for my case.